# convert excel based model to programming model

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, algorithm, data-structures

I have an excel model that is used for running scenario simulation. There is a push to move the analysis to python/javascript for efficiency reasons and eventually move to the web. Below is a snaphot of how the excel model is setup.

The columns represents days which determine working and non working days in a calendar. The rows have variables which quantify how the day is progressing. In other words, the day based var (row) is populated on input. The individual columns then calculate formulas based on the day variable. I have oversimplified to illustrate however there are at least 100 rows with different variables and the 365 days to simulate. Finally, there is an optimization row which is a variable that will be altered to find the best solution.

Now, i need to move this data structure to either Javascript or Python. I understand I need to use 2D arrays to accomplish this task. Any packages and/ or methods that i can utilize to execute this model will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the python `pandas` library, which provides a `DataFrame` which is similar to Excel. Its underlying mechanism is a multidimensional array for fast computations but you can access and modify it in a structured way, create new columns programmatically and apply custom functions as well as similar built-in functions to Excel.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the feedback. I have used Dataframe but its a bit complex to accomplish what i have in mind. Do you know of a excel like package for web.